# Undefined function call lower()

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, dataset, typed

I am getting the following exception in my sqlite query:

> The expression contains undefined function call lower()

I've got a very simple SQLite typed dataset in VS2012.

I'm parsing a large amount of data and want to check if a row already exists prior to adding a  new row.

I'm using the `.select()` method to return an array of datarows. If the length of the array is zero I add a new new. Simple!

All has been working well, but I have added a check to prevent duplicate rows being added if the case is wrong. I am storing filenames.

The select statement is:

```
"lower(FileName) = '" + EscapeFileName(strFileName).ToLower() + "'"
```

However I get the above error on the **lower(FileName)**. If I remove this is works fine, but obviously the check is not comparable.

The statement works as expected in SQLiteAdmin.

Comment: If you've found that an answer worked for you, please remember to "accept" it for the sake of future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a .NET `DataTable` (the result of a query) and you are calling [`DataTable.Select(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) passing in a where clause.

This where clause is processed by .NET, not by SQLite (as pointed out by Tim). You cannot use SQLite (or any other DBMS) function in the Select function for the DataTable. You can use these functions:

> - **CONVERT** – converts particular expression to a specified .NET Framework type
> - **LEN** – gets the length of a string
> - **ISNULL** – checks an expression and either returns the checked expression or a replacement value
> - **IIF** – gets one of two values depending on the result of a logical expression
> - **TRIM** – removes all leading and trailing blank characters like \r, \n, \t, ‚ ‘
> - **SUBSTRING** – gets a sub-string of a specified length, starting at a specified point in the string

See [DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) for more information.

Comment: So the WHERE clause is never sent to SQLite... Hmmm... So do I need to adjust the TableAdapter so it always returns the file name in lower case, as that will be executed by SQLite right?

Comment: That would seem like a good strategy to me, but obviously you are the only one with access to the code. (See update)

Comment: So have hit my first problem. All appears to be working OK until you issue the `.Update()`. Because of the `Lower(FileName) As [FileName]` in the adapter the automatically created **INSERT** statement isn't saving the FileName back to the table. I need to work out how to write a custom query for the **INSERT**.

Comment: So I have now created custom INSERT and UPDATE queries using the wizard in VS2012 and used the default names InsertQuery and UpdateQuery. When the wizard generated my UPDATE and INSERT queries it couldn't read the column name used in the Lower() call so I added the column name manually. The error I get implies that the FileName is not being passed because of the NOT NULL on the column. Do I need to define the @Parameters anywhere or should these be generated automatically for the query/tableadapter?

Answer (score 1):

`The statement works as expected in SQLiteAdmin.`

The client-side data object does not invoke a server-side function but a client-side function.

EDIT: P.S. The DataTable has a [CaseSensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.casesensitive.aspx) option which can be set to false.

P.P.S.  Once you have the set of records in a .NET data object (i.e. your select has been executed and the row set has been retrieved)  any further filtering of data by the data object's built-in methods  (select, find, etc) are operating on the local, client-side *disconnected* data; a "conversation" with the database is not ongoing.  These client-side methods are not "passing the instruction through" to the database.  Read up on the Disconnected Recordset model.

Comment: The lower(FileName) is processed by SQLite. The result of EscapeFileName(strFileName).ToLower() is used. There is no client-side function invoked anywhere:

`"lower(FileName) = 'this-is-in-lower-case.txt'"`

Comment: @Tim You are correct, but your answer is extremely confusing unless you already know what the problem is. You may want to revise by explaining the difference, etc. It would also be helpful to offer a solution to the actual problem.

Comment: @Cyborgx37:  will do.  Added a P.S. with solution.